# Share a variable between two classes

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, variables

I have two different .cs windows in just 1 project. Each one runs a different part of my program. But now I need to use a variable (i) of mainwindow.cs in Form.cs. This variable changes all the time.
How can I do it?

MAINWINDOW.CS

```
   namespace samples
   {
     using System.IO;
     ........
     public partial class MainWindow : Window
       {
       float i;     
       }
    }
```

FORM1.CS

```
    namespace samples
    {
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
        InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        ....
        chart1.Series["Pakistan"].Points.AddXY(i, j);
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: share it via a global modifier ie `static`?

Comment: either make it static or pass it to the constructor of Form1

Comment: You could keep a reference of one form in the other.

Comment: Are they two separate applications?  Does MainWindow have an instance of Form1?

Answer (score 2):

If you declare your variable without an access modifier as you have done, it is implicitly `private` and thus only accessible within the class where it is declared (`MainWindow` in this case).  You can add an access modifier:

```
internal float i;
```

This will allow you to access `i` from other classes within your assembly, like `Form1`.

See MSDN for more information on access modifiers: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wxh6fsc7.aspx

You should almost never expose fields like `i` outside of a class, though; instead what you want to do is use a property:

```
private float i;

public float I
{
    get { return i; }
    set { i = value; }
}
```

Better yet, you could make use of an auto-implemented property so you don't even need to have a backing field (`i`):

```
public float I { get; set; }
```

There are many reasons why exposing properties rather than fields is better.  [Here is one source on the topic](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vbteam/archive/2009/09/04/properties-vs-fields-why-does-it-matter-jonathan-aneja.aspx) (it's centered around VB, but the theories should be the same).

Addendum: please consider proper naming conventions for variables.  `i` is not a good name for your variable.

Answer (score 0):

your default access modifier is private if you don't mention it . Make it public

```
public float i {get; set;}
```